# Is it possible to build Kivy app on Python 3 for Android?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

I have Kivy app on Python 3.4, and I'm trying to find out if it's possible to build it for Android. I am novice at applications building, [docs](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-with-python-for-android) says I need Python 2.7, buildozer requiers Python 2 too, but I've found that there is [some Python 3 support for Android](https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/downloads/detail?name=Python3ForAndroid_r6.apk). So do I need to rewrite my app on Python 2 or is there a way to stay with Python 3?

Comment: I have the same concern, making the choice to learn Python 3.X after already studying the documentation of (C)Python. reverting to 2.7 is something that I'd want to avoid as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: python-for-android now [supports Python 3](http://inclem.net/2016/01/10/kivy/python3_support_in_python_for_android/).**

The Kivy android build tools support only python2 right now. The link you post is not related to kivy.

So yes, you'll need to convert your app to support python2. This often trivial, with the main potential exceptions being if you do significant str/unicode mangling.

I don't know when kivy's tools will support python3. It may currently be waiting on some other internal changes to our python-for-android, to use an sdl2 based bootstrap rather than, or alternatively to, our current java one.

Edit (21/07/2015): I've rewritten a lot of python-for-android to (amongst other things) move towards python3 support. It can now build with an SDL2 backend that should work with python3, but it doesn't yet have a working python3 recipe.

Answer (score 1):

As of today [Kivy site shows Kivy now supports Python 3.4 32 and 64-bit](http://kivy.org/#download) development on Windows. Don't forget to get the Android Kivy launcher for Android listed on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Python could be used for developing mobile apps for Android and iOS.

I created an Android game that is completely developed in Python using Kivy. It is called **CoinTex** available here at Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=coin.tex.cointexreactfast.

The source code of the game is available here at GitHub: https://github.com/ahmedfgad/CoinTex.

I also wrote a book that will be published this year  for building Android apps using Python. It is titled "**Building Android Apps in Python Using Kivy with Android Studio: With Pyjnius, Plyer, and Buildozer**"  available here at Amazon: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/1484250303](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484250303). It discusses the details of developing this game from scratch in 2 of its chapters.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this question is asked 5 years before but we need to answer now.Python is a rapidly developing language gaining it's users since years. The major fault with the python is the older version doesn't get compatible with the newer version. So the packages which are developed with the older versions need to be updated every time . hence it takes time to update the packages. Even two years back buildozer used to support only python 2 now it has updated and there is another tool developed by the kivy fython-for-android helps you to build the apps.
[1]: https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/#usage

So the future app development may depend on the python for it's simplicity and work with the sdk's.